Extracting table of contents from PDFs
I have a reasonably large personal library with books in various formats. I have tried to organize their metadata, including a text field containing the tables of contents. At the moment I am using the 'Area Text Selection' feature from my document reader to copy the text. Doing this for DJVUs with djview yields nicely formatted tables of contents, like this:
CONTENTS
1. EXPERIMENTS
1.1. The definition of an experiment ..... 1
1.2. Algebras of events as Boolean algebras .... 6
1.3. Operations with experiments ...... 9
1.4. Canonical representation of polynomials of events . . 12
....

I emphasize that all I did was drag my mouse across the page and click "Copy Text". If I try this with a PDF the structure is completely lost and I have to spend some time cleaning up the text selection, moving the page and section numbers around. I might get something like this:
Table of Contents
I
 Introduction
1
 Introduction
1.1
 Table of Contents
1.2
 Acknowledgments
1
3
3
6
II
....

I am looking for a PDF reader that can similarly copy the text but with the 'structure' preserved. The fact that DJVU readers have this capability tells me this ought to be possible.
Note: I am not talking about extracting ToCs from the bookmarks: many of my PDFs don't have any. I'd also like to avoid a CLI tool that has to process the entire file: I just want it to pick the text I select, but with the newlines and overall structure intact.

by the way, good on you to keep a library around! I just tend to use zotero for that.


I am looking for a PDF reader that can similarly copy the text but with the 'structure' preserved. The fact that DJVU readers have this capability tells me this ought to be possible.

But you would be mistaken, in general: DJVU documents contain more of the original metadata; especially, if you have a DJVU of a book, chances are this is directly generated from the TeX or ROFF source that book was built from, and retains that structural information.
PDFs, on the other hand, often are simply "you put this letter here, and the next letter exactly there, and the next letter exactly there…", so that a PDF viewer has to take more "guesses" what the text flow was when you select and copy and paste. And, very typically, PDF viewers simply select all glyphs in the order of production by the PDF (think of PDF as something that produces visible output rather than a plain text with prettification information) between the first character that you crossed when starting to select, and the last character when you stopped. If your table of contents is actually stored column-wise, then that can surprisingly put all the first column, in your example, "I","1", … first, then the second column.
For example, when you take this page (from 802.11-2012.pdf),

and select from the first "1." to somewhere behind "Definitions…", you get the following in atril:

and the following in okular:

So, the structure you're hoping for simply isn't there in the document, and two different viewers already interpret what your intention was when selecting things differently. And, both wrongly.
okular has a "rectangle" select which essentially does the same as the "normal" text select, but excludes any characters that would not have been in the rectangle. So, while it only includes the correct things, it doesn't get you the right order.
Now, that doesn't mean there's not one viewer that'd be better than the others, generally. But my experience is that there's essentially as many different attempts to do the right thing as there's different PDF engines, and with the amount of variation you get, there's no clear winner. While above, atril was "less wrong" than okular, the same experiment with the CCSDS 131.0-B-3 "blue book" ToC yields the rather ridiculous:

where okular's area select works somewhat better
The one viewer that kind of works most of the time, but is annoying to use because it doesn't allow you to start a selection within anything that's a hyperlink in a PDF (and most ToC entries are, by their nature, hyperlinks) is (sadly?) the chromium browser's built-in PDF viewer. So, maybe try that!

Thanks for a very detailed answer. I cannot but conclude the people and companies behind this format's popularity have set back humanity significantly.

@Luke nah, that's unjustified hating on a file format. Before, we used to throw around postscript files, which were worse in every way and the windows world (read:99% of businesses) just directly sent around Microsoft Word files with macros enabled. PDF was (and is) a huge leap forward. DJVU is a super niche format that outside of a couple nerds nobody knows how to produce. And the problem here isn't the format, it's the fact that real-world viewers are bad. Come on – there's a correct way to select and copy text in a "left to right, top to bottom" document, and it's just not been implemented.

Looking on a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system for command line tools to extract text from a PDF file.
Used USB Type-C Spec R2.4 - October 2024.pdf for which which GNOME Document Viewer 46.3.1 has renders the contents as:



pdf2txt
pdf2txt version v20221105 output the raw text output on the table of contents:
^LRelease 2.4 
October 2024 

- 3 - 

USB Type-C® Cable and 
Connector Specification 

1.1 
1.2 
1.3 
1.4 

Contents 
Specification Editor ...................................................................................................................................................................................... 18 
Specification Work Group Contributors .............................................................................................................................................. 18 
Pre-Release Draft Industry Reviewing Companies That Provided Feedback ..................................................................... 26 
Revision History ............................................................................................................................................................................................. 27 
Introduction .......................................................................................................................................................................................... 28 
1 
Purpose ........................................................................................................................................................
................................ 28 
Scope ............................................................................................................................................................................................. 28 
Related Documents ................................................................................................................................................................. 28 
Conventions ................................................................................................................................................................................ 29 
1.4.1  Precedence ............................................................................................................................................................................ 29 
1.4.2  Keywords ............................................................................................................................................................................... 29 
1.4.3  Numbering............................................................................................................................................................................. 30 
Terms and Abbreviations ..................................................................................................................................................... 30 
Overview ................................................................................................................................................................................................ 36 
Introduction ............................................................................................................................................................................... 36 
USB Type-C Receptacles, Plugs and Cables .................................................................................................................. 37 
Configuration Process ............................................................................................................................................................ 38 
2.3.1  Source-to-Sink Attach/Detach Detection ................................................................................................................. 39 
2.3.2  Plug Orientation/Cable Twist Detection .................................................................................................................. 39 
2.3.3 

Then in the extracted text the section numbers and title and page numbers don't always line up. I.e. pdf2txt doesn't help.
pdftotext
pdftotext version 24.02.0 produces the following text:
-3-

USB Type-C® Cable and
Connector Specification

Contents
Specification Editor ......................................................................................................................................................................................18
Specification Work Group Contributors ..............................................................................................................................................18
Pre-Release Draft Industry Reviewing Companies That Provided Feedback .....................................................................26
Revision History .............................................................................................................................................................................................27
1

Introduction ..........................................................................................................................................................................................28
1.1

Purpose ........................................................................................................................................................................................28

1.2

Scope .............................................................................................................................................................................................28

1.3

Related Documents .................................................................................................................................................................28

1.4

Conventions ................................................................................................................................................................................29

1.4.1

Precedence ............................................................................................................................................................................29

1.4.2

Keywords ...............................................................................................................................................................................29

1.4.3

Numbering.............................................................................................................................................................................30

pdftotext looks to do a better job of ordering the section numbers and titles and page numbers than pdf2txt did, but might still require some manual post processing.
The other answer has already explained that the PDF document format isn't designed to get back to the source text in a coherent order, which explains the limitations with such tools.
